# Spring Security X.509 authentication without user-service

Tags: authentication, spring-security, x509certificate, client-certificates, x509

I'm using Spring Security (v3.1.3) for X.509 authentication in my web-application. Users and roles are stored in the Database, but I don't actually need to do it, as CNs of client certificates conform to "[ROLE] - [USERNAME]" schema, which means I already have username and role from the certificate itself. So how to eliminate the database without too much effort? Should I write my own implementation of user-service, which will populate UserDetails, or is there more graceful method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the simplest option is probably to write a custom `AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>`. The implementations would be something like this:

```
UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken token) {
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate[)token.getCredentials();

    // Extract what you want from the certificate
    ...

    // Create the user information
    UserDetails user = ...

    return user;
}
```

You should be able to use a reference to this bean directly in the `user-service-ref` namespace attribute  `<x509 user-service-ref='yourUserServiceBean' />`.

Comment: I don't need anything from the certificate besides username which is extracted via Spring's `subject-principal-regex`, so I ended up implementing `UserDetailsService` interface and returning locally constructed `UserDetails` with default ROLE from it's `loadUserByUsername` method. Application is a tiny one and won't ever have more than one default role anyway.