# Spring security x509 authentication without user service, instead a token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, x509

With Spring Security 3, we have been able to use the answer described here: [Spring Security X.509 authentication without user-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563397/spring-security-x-509-authentication-without-user-service) to authenticate using a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken`.

However, since upgrading to Spring Security 5, I'm now getting an error as the class described above does not implement `UserDetailsService` - but UserDetailsService loads by username, not by details - so how can I keep using x509 auth with a token in Spring Security 5?